# How to include more JavaScript inside Atom editor by Github?

Tags: javascript, code-snippets, atom-editor

I've been playing with snippets for Atom editor,
and see that I've learned I can include
JavaScript inside of a snippet, as my example shows.

(It inserts a TODO Comment with date)

```
TODO: (RAM) Fix this  -  2014-11-23 20:55
HELLO
```

**How can I include MORE JavaScript.?**

For example

inside the snippet to set

```
var= to something
```

or

```
call a JS library
```

or

```
ask for input from user i.e. confirm();
```

and proceed on basis of confirm() function.

Any help would be appreciated, I looked for a long time,
but not much documentation on this. Submlime Text's snippets allowed lots of code to be inserted via Python.

Thanks
~Rob

Inside file snippets.cson

```
'.source.js':

'Date TODO: insert':
'prefix': 'datetd'
'body': """
TODO: (RAM) $1  -  #{datetime = new Date(); datetime.getFullYear()}-#{(datetime.getMonth()+1)}-#{datetime.getDate()} #{datetime.getHours()}:#{datetime.getMinutes()}
 #{"hello".toUpperCase(); }
 $2
"""
```

Comment: Thanks to Lee, I'm starting to get this, here is example [GIST](https://gist.github.com/readerpal/7cfe89936c382c08628d).  I posted GIST, since I couldn't get the indenting to work on stackoverflow ( Coffee crisps demands correct indenting of code).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** With the merge of [atom/atom#4791](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/4971), the capability of putting CoffeeScript code in CSON configuration files has been removed from Atom. The rest of the answer has been left intact for historic reference.

Actually, the syntax of the file is CoffeeScript (hence `.cson` as in CoffeeScript Object Notation), not JavaScript. It just so happens that you typed in JavaScript that is allowed as CoffeeScript. CoffeeScript doesn't use the `var` keyword, so you can assign variables like you did in your example:

```
datetime = new Date()
```

The other items, you'll probably have to get a little creative. I don't believe that the snippets package was intended to be used in this manner, which is why the lack of documentation on the "feature".